# XCode: How to declare a UIWebView object in Storyboard?

Tags: xcode4, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView object sitting in a UIViewController.  I am trying to load this html file using this code for which I am getting this error: Use of undeclared identifier "webView". I have labeled both the UIViewController and UIWebView in the Identity section Storyboard, which do nothing.  I'm wondering if I have to somehow connect the UIWebView to something in my .h file?

```
  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .H file should look like this.

```
    @interface slTableViewController () {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *myWebView;
```

of course this will mean you'll have to add `@synthesize myWebView;` to your .m file!

Comment: I don't have a UIViewController... I deleted it and replaced it with a UITableViewController.. when I put your code in the UITableViewController.h file, I get errors, saying I'm not allowed to do it.  I think we're on the right track, but I don't know how to fix this.  I took a screen shot and you can look at it here: http://www.imgur.com/ZaNA6

Comment: Ignore the above...
.h file appears to be good... .m file has an error... here are both: http://www.pastebin.com/Pw0J7p9U